# Do external CSS files with relative image paths reference external images?

Tags: html, css, image, relative-path

On **domain1.com** I have a simple html page:

```
<h1 class="hello-world">Hello World!</h1>
```

This page references an *external* CSS file which is hosted over on **domain2.com**. All of the images within that CSS file are referenced using relative paths. E.g:

```
h1.hello-world {
background-image:url(/images/cute-kitten.gif);
}
```

When I load the page on domain1 does the browser try to reference the image *'domain1.com/images/cute-kitten.gif'* or *'domain2.com/images/cute-kitten.gif'*?

And will the result be the **same in all** (current) **browsers**?

Comment: Couldn't you test this yourself and see?

Comment: Surely you could just check this yourself, as I assume it would be a lot quicker than asking on SO....?

Comment: Hey guys, yup I did do some initial testing locally and it seemed to agree with the answers people have given here, however having looked on SO for similar questions a few people had reported that IE (which I can't get access to just at the moment) handled relative URLS in external CSS differently, so it would try to reference them on the domain requesting the CSS file rather than the domain the CSS file was hosted on. Having seen the answers here i'm confident that this is not the case and that it will behave as expected on all browsers, so it has been a great help. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [CSS Level 2 specification document](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#uri), relative URIs are always resolved using the URI of the stylesheet which includes the path.

> In order to create modular style sheets that are not dependent on the
>   absolute location of a resource, authors may use relative URIs. [...]
>   **For CSS style sheets, the base URI is that of the style sheet, not
>   that of the source document.**

Therefore, it will always be resolved to `http://domain2.com/images/cute-kitten.gif` on all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

As per [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#url):

> Partial URLs are interpreted relative to the source of the style
>   sheet, not relative to the document

In your example, the URI would result in `domain2.com/images/cute-kitten.gif`.